# How to check if array has some elements same as another array and to pop those elements out of array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an `array` like this:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(16) "1785328791698338"
}
```

And other `array` like this:

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  string(17) "10207252567926988"
  [1]=>
  string(17) "10208823390691752"
  [2]=>
  string(17) "10209064245580796"
  [3]=>
  string(16) "1274474365912572"
  [4]=>
  string(16) "1294280923934896"
  [5]=>
  string(16) "1317727711586522"
  [6]=>
  string(16) "1785328791698338"
}
```

I should check if some of the elements(in this case only one, but it can vary) from first array are same as some elements in second array, and if they are, to remove them from first array. I tried doing it this way, but it does't work:

```
function findSameValuesOfArrays($arrayOne,$arrayTwo){
         $newArray=array();
         foreach($arrayOne as $a){
            $newArray[0]=$a;
         }
         foreach($arrayTwo as $b){
            $newArray[1]=$b;
         }
         if (strpos($newArray[1],$newArray[0])) {
            return true;
         }

    }
```

This is just to find if there are same elements, and then i would probably unset key where those values are. But function returns `NULL`.

Comment: In simple terms you can say: You want to delete all elements from the second array in the first one. This means as explained in the duplicate `$result = array_diff($yourFirstArray, $secondArray);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`array_diff` does exactly what you want.

```
$sourceArr = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$filterArr = array(2,4);
$result = array_diff($sourceArr, $filterArr);
var_dump($result);
```

Result:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [2]=>
  int(3)
  [4]=>
  int(5)
}
```

https://3v4l.org/IvmHH

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_intersect` here like as:

```
$arr3 = array_intersect($arr1,$arr2);
print_r($arr3);
```

Here is an Examples:

https://3v4l.org/kqPV2

https://3v4l.org/qZpgf

Or You can read more at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$arrFirst = array("1785328791698338","10207252567926988");
$arrMain = array("10207252567926988","10208823390691752","10209064245580796","1274474365912572","1294280923934896","1317727711586522","1785328791698338");
foreach ($arrFirst as $key => $value) {
   if(in_array($value, $arrMain )) { // check if value exist in seconf array
        unset($arrFirst[$key]); // if yes - unset that value
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **array_intersect** here to  returns an array containing all the values of array1 that are present in all the arguments.  and then array_diff

```
$arrFirst = array(0=>"1785328791698338",1=>"1785328791698334",3=>"1785328791698336");
$arrMain = array(0=>"10207252567926988",1=>"10208823390691752",3=>"10209064245580796",4=>"1785328791698338");
$arrIntersect = array_intersect( $arrMain,$arrFirst);
$resultArray = array_diff($arrFirst, $arrIntersect);
print "<pre>";print_r($resultArray);
```